# Eating competition central limit problem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Nate is a competitive eater specializing in eating hot dogs. From
past experience we know that it takes him on average $15$ seconds to consume one hot
dog, with a standard deviation of $4$ seconds. In this year's hot dog eating contest
he hopes to consume $64$ hot dogs in just $15$ minutes. Use the CLT to approximate
the probability that he achieves this feat of skill.

I am having trouble setting up this problem.

Outline:
Let $S_n:=X_1+X_2+\dots X_{64}$ where each $X_i$ is the $i^{th}$ hot dog consumed. We have $E[S_n]=64*15=960$, $Var(S_n)=64*4=256.$ Using CLT, I get $0.6293$ but the answer key says its $.0304$. I'm guessing my setup is wrong? I'm not sure whether I should work with in terms of seconds or minutes.

Comment: Assuming i.i.d. $\{X_i\}$ we get $Var(S_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{64}Var(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{64}4^2 = 1024$ seconds-squared. Recall that variance $\sigma^2$ is the square of standard deviation $\sigma$. (Here $\sigma=4$ seconds.) It seems easiest to work everything in units of seconds.

Comment: Wow, I forgot about that. Thanks.